# Neural networks always ouputs the same value

Tags: python, networking, backpropagation

```
import numpy as np

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoidPrime(x):
    return x * (1 - x)

def cost(x, y):
    return np.sum((y - x) ** 2)

def dcost(x, y):
    return (x - y)

hidden_weights = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(2, 2))
output_weights = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(1, 2))

hidden_biases = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(2, 1))
output_biases = np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=(1, 1))

def train(rate, hw, ow, hb, ob, i, o):
    input_activations  = sigmoid(i)

    hidden_sums = np.dot(hw, input_activations) + hb
    hidden_activations = sigmoid(hidden_sums)

    output_sums = np.dot(ow, hidden_activations) + ob
    output_activations = sigmoid(output_sums)

    output_deltas = dcost(output_activations, o) * sigmoidPrime(output_activations)
    hidden_deltas = np.dot(ow.T, output_deltas) * sigmoidPrime(hidden_activations)

    ob -= rate * output_deltas
    ow -= rate * np.dot(output_deltas, hidden_activations.T)

    hb -= rate * hidden_deltas
    hw -= rate * np.dot(hidden_deltas, input_activations.T)
    return hw, ow, hb, ob

def predict(hw, ow, hb, ob, i):
    input_activations  = sigmoid(i)

    hidden_sums = np.dot(hw, input_activations) + hb
    hidden_activations = sigmoid(hidden_sums)

    output_sums = np.dot(ow, hidden_activations) + ob
    output_activations = sigmoid(output_sums)
    return output_activations

rate = 0.1

for i in range(0, 10000):
    hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases =\
        train(rate, hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[0], [0]]), np.array([[0]]))
    hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases =\
        train(rate, hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[1], [0]]), np.array([[1]]))
    hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases =\
        train(rate, hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[0], [1]]), np.array([[1]]))
    hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases =\
        train(rate, hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[1], [1]]), np.array([[0]]))

print(predict(hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[0], [0]])))
print(predict(hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[1], [0]])))
print(predict(hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[0], [1]])))
print(predict(hidden_weights, output_weights, hidden_biases, output_biases, np.array([[1], [1]])))
```

Everything seems to be correct, but it always outputs a float around 0.5. The output should be near 0 or 1 since the network predicts the output of a XOR gate. I have done the maths and rechecked it dozens of times without success.

However, I am a C++ programmer and this was my try at a simple implementation of a neural network before I do it in C++. Thus, I am not that familiar with python.

Comment: It looks like the issue is a confusion between local and global scope. You're treating your weights and biases as if they're global variables, but then you're passing them in as local variables into your functions which then don't return anything. Being that mutable global variables tend to be a bad idea, I'd suggest either have your function return values, which then could get passed back into the next train function, OR, you use a python class to store the state of your network weights, and just update the weights of an instance of your network class with your train function (or method)

Comment: To get a better sense of how things are done in Python, I recommend checking out how things are done in [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/). I also recommend checking out this book: [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html)

Comment: I refactored the code, but the problem persists.

Comment: Try printing out values in your training loop to ensure they are changing

Comment: I did so and the weights are changing. I updated the code in the original post.